# What is the best way to keep temporary version of database while it is being updated in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I currently have a model in ruby on rails which stores information, but I want to update this information every hour. What's the best way to keep a temporary version of the data while my database is being updated?

I have tried using

```
@temp = Lecture.deep_dup
```

But this gets cleared when I delete all from my database.

What's the best approach?

***Edit*** :
Here's the code that does the updating

```
lecture = Lecture.create(name:course_name,section:section,term:term_name,days:course_days,s_time:start_time,e_time:end_time,location:location,also_reg:also_reg,status:status)
lecture.save
```

This runs for a few minutes while it scrapes a website

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the updating hourly?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I added the way I'm saving new data to the active record after I clear the database, does this help?

Comment: see my answer, you can wrap your code inside transaction.  But "clear the database" ? where is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some task that mucks with all the data, just wrap that code inside a transaction.

UPDATE based on your update

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  lecture = Lecture.create(
    name: course_name, section: section, term: term_name, days: course_days,
    s_time: start_time, e_time: end_time, location: location, also_reg: also_reg, status: status)
  lecture.save
end
```

UPDATE 2 per comment, In this case it would be better to do:

```
Lecture.transaction do
  lecture = Lecture.create(
    name: course_name, section: section, term: term_name, days: course_days,
    s_time: start_time, e_time: end_time, location: location, also_reg: also_reg, status: status)
    lecture.save
  end
end
```

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

But if your `Lecture.create` method is long running, I would suggest you move it to a worker / background job.  See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: `Lecture.transaction` is preferable. Especially for multiple db setups.